# PrestaShop won't install due to an unwritable sessions path

Tags: php, session, prestashop

I'm trying to install PrestaShop on my Virtual Server hosted at [Forpsi](http://www.forpsi.com/). The installation process, however, complains that the session path is not writable:

```
Your PHP sessions path is not writable - check with your hosting provider: /var/lib/php/session
```

I found two advices on the Internet:

1. To make sure that the particular folder (/var/lib/php/session) has assigned rights to write for everyone. I issued `chmod -R o+rw /var/lib/php/session` but it did not help.
2. To change the `session.save_path` value in the `php.ini` file to `"/tmp/"`.

To find the correct `php.ini` file, I run the following command:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

and got the following answer:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
```

So I changed `session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"` to `session.save_path = "/tmp/"` in `/etc/php.ini` and restarted apache via:

```
service httpd restart
```

Nevertheless, when rerunning the installation script, I still get the same error.

I tried to verify whether the session.save_path was changed or not by running `phpinfo()` and indeed it still shows:

```
session.save_path (Local Value: /var/lib/php/session, Master Value: /var/lib/php/session)
```

I am running multiple websites at the same host, and other applications (including a WordPress installation) work fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FYI: Not all applications use PHP sessions. The given example *WordPress* for example, ***does not***. Also as this sounds configuration related, you should contact your host for the support options you have here. The hoster normally can tell you exactly where to change the php.ini file for your account. This can be very different across hosters, so just providing the error description is likely not enough.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have opened a ticket at customer support at Forpsi.

Comment: PrestaShop 1.5.5 installer now implements a cookie mode when the session does not work: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/archive/release.zip